# Free hosting video platform compatible with AVPlayer support

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

I am trying to play a video from my iOS app when tapping a button, but I was wondering how and where I can host my video (for free) so that I can play the video in an AVPlayer using the URL. I tried hosting the video on youtube, and setting the AVPlayer URL to the youtube video URL, but the player loads forever. I included my code, it's functional, I just need to know where I can upload my video to get a proper URL.

```
@IBAction func didTapPlayButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "") else {
            return
        }
        // Create an AVPlayer, passing it the HTTP Live Streaming URL.
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

        // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player

        // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
        present(controller, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Indeed, the code you posted seems to be is working fine if you provide a URL pointing to a movie file (such as .mp4). Since a typical youtube URL returns a whole HTML page, you can't easily use AVPlayer for playing YouTube videos. Instead, there's an official library to help you with that: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper
If you're only looking for a suggestion of services where you can host your videos for free, I'm not sure if this community is the most adequate place for that :)

Comment: Thank you, the solution you proposed is functional but since I intend to upload my app on the store, I am not sure how "legal" it is, so I went with Matan's solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to host and serve your video as a binary file.
You can use an object storage (e.g. [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjqrEyMji6AIVTOJ3Ch1CpALPEAAYASAAEgLqEPD_BwE) or [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)) or serve the file through a web API.
Just set the correct [Content-Type](https://help.encoding.com/knowledge-base/article/correct-mime-types-for-serving-video-files/) (e.g. "video/mp4" to help the player recognise the binary file type)

You can then initiate your `AVPlayer` with the URL of the video.

**Please note that Firebase Storage has a very generous free tier, it might be all you need.**

#### For example:

You can take a look at this video file:
https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4

This file is hosted as a binary and the Content-Type is set to video/mp4.

Try to initiate your AVPlayer with the above URL and see that it works.

Comment: Thank you, I followed the first part of these instructions to upload it on S3 for free https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/tutorials/create/beginner/s3-video/, placed the link in my code and it works perfectly.